# cmd - delete IP from rule (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: windows-command-prompt, netsh

I'm banning IPs using the Windows Firewall with these commands in cmd (actually in C# but using the cmd):

```
pushd advfirewall firewall
set rule name="BlockedIPs" new remoteip="1.2.3.4" action=block protocol=any dir=in
popd
```

How do I remove a single IP from that rule using cmd again, without deleting the whole rule? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like this :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="BlockedIPs" remoteip="1.2.3.4"
```

This should delete the rule where remoteip is `1.2.3.4` from the rule named `BlockedIPs`

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back to the accept button as soon as I tried it!

Comment: Yeah, I guess adding and removing single IPs from an existent rule isn't as easily possible in Windows as I thought. I ended up creating and deleting a new rule for each IP, so this solution worked fine.